# What is the most native-like way to prompt user with a choice menu in Phonegap/Cordova?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm using [org.apache.cordova.camera plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/doc/index.md) and I need to ask a user to choose a camera's source type:

```
Camera.PictureSourceType = {
    PHOTOLIBRARY : 0,
    CAMERA : 1,
    SAVEDPHOTOALBUM : 2
};
```

I far as I understand, there's no way to make this plugin to prompt a user to select the source of a photos. So what's the most native way to achieve this?

Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 2):

there is no more native way to do this. just add 2 buttons in app, one representing photos, and other videos. after choosing one, show a prompt dialog where user chooses wether to take it from camera or gallery.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so... I decided to go this way (I'm writing my app with Ionic) http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicActionSheet/ Looks sexy.

Comment: By the way, you can't remove text input from cordova promt dialog and leave only the buttons - that's sad...

Comment: well, it doesnt HAVE TO be prompt dialog actually. you can do some modal-like thing (something thats hidden and pop out when needed)